# AttributeError: 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'rotateClockWise'

Tags: python

I am planning to make a pdf rotate/convert tool for self-convenient purposes.

However, the compiler indicates my the rotateClockWise module does not exist. Has anyone had a similar issue with me? or it's simply an environmental problem?

Here is the way I wrote:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader,PdfFileWriter
pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file_path_str.pdf)
pageRotate = pdf_reader.getPage(page).rotateClockWise(90)
```

the compile will report error as :

```
AttributeError: 'PageObject' object has no attribute 'rotateClockWise'
```

Env:
python3.7.0+PyPDF2+pycharm

Answer (score 0):

It's rotateClock**w**ise with lowercase w.

Comment: Thanks Petr, now it works just fine! and sry for my silly question :P